# Cantata (mpd) not playing after upgrading to kubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, sound, mpd

After upgrading from Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 I have no sound in Cantata. When I hit the play button, the progress bar is not advancing.

mpd's log file at `/var/log/mpd/mpd.log` shows:

> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
> exception: Failed to open "My ALSA Device" (alsa)
> exception: nested: Failed to open ALSA device "default": No such file or directory

- Cantata version 2.4.1
- mpd: Music Player Daemon 0.21.20

Answer (score 0):

From all things I tried, I guess in the end it were *two* problems:

### Wrong file permissions of `/etc/mpd.conf`

Run this in a console:

```
mpd -v
```

I don't know what `-v` is doing exactly - it's not even documented at `man mpd` :-( Anyway, if you're getting

> exception: Failed to open '/etc/mpd.conf': Permission denied

... you need to fix this first. Give read access to user "mpd" (group "audio") - or just to anybody :-)

If you're getting

> config_file: loading file /etc/mpd.conf

... this step is OK.

The rest of the output isn't important - it probably just means that mpd is already running (which is OK):

> exception: Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600'
> exception: nested: Failed to bind socket: Address already in use

### Wrong audio device

```
lspci -knn|grep -iA2 audio
```

... shows me that I have *two* devices. Open `mpd.conf` and find

```
audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "My ALSA Device"
#   device      "hw:0,0"    # optional
```

Change the last line to

```
    device      "hw:1,0"    # optional
```

Maybe you need to restart:

```
sudo service mpd restart
```

This fixed it for me :-)